# Changing article text and summary with template_preprocess_node()

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

I use Drupal 7.9 with Views module (if the latter is important). I've created a small module for my site that changes transliteration of Japanese words in articles from Latin to Cyrillics and vice versa (yes, I need such a thing). User sees a form with radio button set, chooses transliteration, his choice goes to $_COOKIE and then I change transliteration in article summary and body based on user's choice. Or better to say I'm trying to change it but it doesn't work. The code goes like this:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    /* Suppose we have a summary containing only one word 'Yamamoto' that has to be changed to 'Ямамото' */
    $variables['node']->body['und'][0]['summary'] = 'Ямамото';
}
```

After this code is executed, the changed variable has the correct value of 'Ямамото'. But in the main page for some reason I see the unchanged 'Yamamoto'. What am I doing wrong? Do I change the wrong field? Do I mess up working with parameters passed by reference? Do I use the wrong hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the node has already been rendered by the time `template_preprocess_node()` is called so changing any values on the node object will have no effect. You can try looking at `$variables['node']->content` to see if you can modify the text in that (I think this is the full HTML rendered node though, so lots of extra text/markup to deal with here).

You're probably better off using [hook_node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_load/7) instead. This gives you a chance to alter the node object directly before it gets rendered.

Comment: Oh. That's why it didn't work for me. Okay, thanks, I'll use $variables['content']. hook_node_load() for some reason is not called in my module, and when i write something plain and simple like 

`function mymodule_node_load($nodes, $types)
{
    die('Died on node_load');
}`

my site happily continues to work. I suspect it has something to do with the fact that I have a form in my module but am not very sure as I'm a newbie to Drupal. So I'll use $variables['content'].

Comment: You can always open another question if you wanna try `hook_node_load()` in the future. Good luck!